# Running multiple insert and update statements inside oracle trigger

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers

I have an oracle trigger to insert data to another table. If i use single update query than it works however if i user multiple commands like update and insert it fails with error following error.

```
ORA-04091: table ADMIN_SMS_HANDLER is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "ADMIN_SMS_TRIG", line 16
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ADMIN_SMS_TRIG'
```

**This works.**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ADMIN_SMS_TRIG AFTER
    INSERT ON ADMIN_SMS_HANDLER
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SMS (
        SMSID,
        ANUMBER,
        BNUMBER,
        MSG,
        APP
    ) VALUES (
        SMSSEQ.NEXTVAL,
        :NEW.SMS_FROM,
        :NEW.SMS_TO,
        :NEW.SMS_TEXT,
        'APP'
    );
END;
```

**But this is not working**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ADMIN_SMS_TRIG AFTER
    INSERT ON ADMIN_SMS_HANDLER
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SMS (
        SMSID,
        ANUMBER,
        BNUMBER,
        MSG,
        APP
    ) VALUES (
        SMSSEQ.NEXTVAL,
        :NEW.SMS_FROM,
        :NEW.SMS_TO,
        :NEW.SMS_TEXT,
        'app'
    );

    UPDATE ADMIN_SMS_HANDLER
    SET
        SENT_DATE = SYSDATE,
        SENT_STATUS = 1,
        UPDATED_BY = 'trigger',
        UPDATED_DATE = SYSDATE
    WHERE
        ID = :NEW.ID;
END;
```

Comment: Because you are trying to update the table on which you have created the trigger.`ADMIN_SMS_HANDLER`. Have your tried the before insert trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with multiple statements.  The issue is that a row-level trigger (generally) cannot reference the table on which it is defined.

Assuming that the intention is to have the trigger automatically populate some columns, you would do that by directly setting values in the `:new` pseudo-record, i.e.

```
:new.sent_date := sysdate;
:new.sent_status := 1;
```

But since you want to modify data in the current row, you'd need to use a `before insert` trigger rather than an `after insert` trigger.  Something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ADMIN_SMS_TRIG 
    BEFORE INSERT ON ADMIN_SMS_HANDLER
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SMS (
        SMSID,
        ANUMBER,
        BNUMBER,
        MSG,
        APP
    ) VALUES (
        SMSSEQ.NEXTVAL,
        :NEW.SMS_FROM,
        :NEW.SMS_TO,
        :NEW.SMS_TEXT,
        'app'
    );

    :new.SENT_DATE := SYSDATE;
    :new.SENT_STATUS := 1;
    :new.UPDATED_BY := 'trigger';
    :new.UPDATED_DATE := SYSDATE;
END;
```